# How to increase the number of columns in the generation of a file in xls - Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I need to generate an Excel file that will have approximately 1000 columns. But at the time of generation the [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) library can only generate 256 columns.

I've tried almost everything: I increased **memory_limit**, **max_execution_time**, ... But nothing worked so far.

**Versions**

- PHP version: 7.0.26
- Laravel version: 5.6
- Package version: 2.1

Here is test code where I try to generate 1000 columns.

**PHP**

```
Excel::create("Test_A", function($excel) {

    $excel->setTitle("Only test");

    $excel->sheet("Test 1", function($sheet) {

        $sheet->loadView('excel');

    })->export('xls');

});
```

**VIEW**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ App::getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
           <tr>
                @for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
                    <th>{{ $i }}</th>
                @endfor
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are exporting as xls `export('xls');`, can you try to export as xlsx ? 256 columns is the maximum for a xls, as it's the Excel < 2007 format

Comment: Wow! That was all! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to export excel using Laravel Excel library.
You need to pass the list of the array as a first parameter and 2nd and 3rd parameter is optional if you want to add a header with the logo then use it else modify a bit and remove that header part.

```
function exportExcel($userList,$clientLogo,$defaultLogo){

// Generate and return the spreadsheet
            Excel::create('User_List', function ($excel) use ($userList,$clientLogo,$defaultLogo) {

                // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
                $excel->setTitle('User List');
                $excel->setCreator('CompanyName')->setCompany('CompanyName');
                $excel->setDescription('User List Reports');

                    $excel->sheet('User List', function($sheet) use ($userList,$path,$clientLogo,$defaultLogo) {

                        //Set header with logo with different coloumn width & height
                        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing;
                        $objDrawing->setPath(public_path('img/'.$defaultLogo));
                        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
                        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
                        $objDrawing->setName('Client Logo');
                        $objDrawing->setResizeProportional(false);
                        $objDrawing->setWidth(100);
                        $objDrawing->setHeight(50);

                        $sheet->setSize('A1', 20, 50);

                        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing;
                        $objDrawing->setPath(public_path('img/'.$clientLogo));
                        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('D1');
                        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
                        $objDrawing->setName('Client Logo');
                        $objDrawing->setResizeProportional(false);
                        $objDrawing->setWidth(100);
                        $objDrawing->setHeight(50);

                        $sheet->setSize('D1', 20, 50);

                        $sheet->fromArray($userList, null, 'A2', false, false);

                        $sheet->cells('A1:D1', function($cells) {

                            $cells->setBackground('#36494F')->setFontColor('#FFFFF')->setFontWeight('bold');
                        });

                        $sheet->mergeCells('A1:D1');
                        $sheet->mergeCells('B1:C1');

                        $sheet->cell('B1', function($cell) {

                            $cell->setValue('User List')->setBackground('#36494F');
                        });

                        $sheet->row(1, function ($row) {

                            $row->setBackground('#36494F')->setFontColor('#FFFFFF')->setFontWeight('bold')->setValue('User Tickets List')->setAlignment('center')->setValignment('center');
                        });

                        $sheet->row(2, function ($row) {

                            $row->setBackground('#FFFFFF')->setFontColor('#36494F')->setFontWeight('bold')->setAlignment('center')->setValignment('center');
                        });

                        for ($i = 3; $i <= count($userList)+1; $i++) {

                            $sheet->cells('A'.$i.':D'.$i, function ($cells) use ($i) {

                                $cells->setBackground(($i%2) == 0 ? '#DCDCDC':'#EDEDEE');
                            });
                        }

                        for ($ascii = ord('A'); $ascii <= ord('D'); $ascii++) {

                            for ($i = 1; $i <= count($userList)+1; $i++) {

                                $sheet->cell(chr($ascii) . $i, function ($cell) {

                                    $cell->setBorder('thin','thin','thin','thin');
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    });


            })->download('xls');

}
```